# menu no Wordpress com 3 níveis

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Eu quero construir um menu no Wordpress com 3 níveis.

Este exemplo tem 2 níveis, o pai e o filho.

Eu quero que o menu tenha mais um nível, para que eu possa criar um menu de 3 níveis com o Wordpress.

Abaixo, à esquerda, um código que se refere a dois níveis de menu.

Exemplo do menu neste  [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11935423/how-do-i-generate-a-custom-menu-sub-menu-system-using-wp-get-nav-menu-items-in-w)

```
<?php
  $menu_name = 'main_nav';
  $locations = get_nav_menu_locations();
  $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations[ $menu_name ] );
  $menuitems = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu->term_id, array( 'order' => 'DESC' ) );
?>

<nav>
<ul class="main-nav">
    <?php
    $count = 0;
    $submenu = false;
    foreach( $menuitems as $item ):
        $link = $item->url;
        $title = $item->title;
        // item does not have a parent so menu_item_parent equals 0 (false)
        if ( !$item->menu_item_parent ):
        // save this id for later comparison with sub-menu items
        $parent_id = $item->ID;
    ?>

    <li class="item">
        <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" class="title">
            <?php echo $title; ?>
        </a>
    <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ( $parent_id == $item->menu_item_parent ): ?>

            <?php if ( !$submenu ): $submenu = true; ?>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
            <?php endif; ?>

                <li class="item">
                    <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" class="title"><?php echo $title; ?></a>
                </li>

            <?php if ( $menuitems[ $count + 1 ]->menu_item_parent != $parent_id && $submenu ): ?>
            </ul>
            <?php $submenu = false; endif; ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ( $menuitems[ $count + 1 ]->menu_item_parent != $parent_id ): ?>
    </li>                           
    <?php $submenu = false; endif; ?>

<?php $count++; endforeach; ?>

</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Seria interessante colocar o CSS, apesar do assunto ser Wordpress. Assim pode conseguir uma resposta mais facilmente.

Comment: Então o CSS não seria importante, apenas colocar a estrutura para poder fazer um menu de 3 níveis. Pode ser uma estrutura simples de <ul><li> </li> </ul>

Assim daria para fazer em qualquer tipo de menu. Eu consegui uma boa solução vou postar aqui.

Comment: No caso este seria um código para simplificar a programação do Wordpress, que para criação de menus sem plugins é muito confuso e não da suporte para menus de 3 níveis. Consegui aplicar uma solução.

Comment: Se alguém tiver uma solução melhor, postem por favor que eu dou a recompensa.

Comment: A vantagem de usar o menu desta forma é que você consegue usar a estrutura HTML que quiser. Ao contrário da função do Wordpress nativo que muitas  vezes você não consegue fazer um mega menu ou um menu com uma programação mais complexa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Wordpress não tem uma função simples pronta para criar submenus de 3 níveis.
Porém com esta classe que eu criei ele permite que você possa criar um menu de 3 níveis facilmente.

O arquivo da classe pode ser salvo como menu.php ou o nome que desejar.

Lembrando que será necessário trocar o nome do menu de acordo com o nome do seu menu utilizado, pois senão não conseguirá buscar os dados do menu.

```
$menu_name = 'header-menu';
```

Esta classe vai servir como uma espécie de back end do Wordpress para poder criar um menu de 3 níveis.

```
<?php
// classe com as variáveis que você quer puxar do back end
class Menu
{
    public $titulo;
    public $id;
    public $url;
    public $submenu;
}

$menu_name = 'header-menu';
$locations = get_nav_menu_locations();
$menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object($locations[ $menu_name ]);
$menuitems = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id, array('order' => 'DESC'));
$submenu = false;
$id_anterior = 0;
$set_menu = false;
foreach( $menuitems as $item ):

    //adiciona o menu
    if (!$item->menu_item_parent){
        // o menu precisa ser adicionado depois de setar seus filhos logo 
        //a variavel setmenu vai certificar que você consiga setar os 
        //filhos do menu corretamente
        if ($set_menu == true) { $menus[] = $myMenu;  $set_menu = false;}
        if ($set_menu == false) { $set_menu = true;}

        $myMenu = new Menu();
        $myMenu->titulo = $item->title;
        $myMenu->id = $item->ID;
        $myMenu->url = $item->url;
    } 
    else 
    { 
        //adiciona o submenu
        if ($id_anterior != $item->menu_item_parent) { 
            $mySubmenu = new Menu();
            $mySubmenu->titulo = $item->title;
            $mySubmenu->id = $item->ID;
            $mySubmenu->url = $item->url;
            $myMenu->submenu[] = $mySubmenu; 
        }
        //adiciona o submenu

        //adiciona o subsubmenu
        if ($id_anterior == $item->menu_item_parent) { 
            $mySubSubmenu = new Menu();
            $mySubSubmenu->titulo = $item->title;
            $mySubSubmenu->id = $item->ID;
            $mySubSubmenu->url =  $item->url;
            $mySubmenu->submenu[] = $mySubSubmenu; 
        }
        if ($id_anterior != $item->menu_item_parent){
            $id_anterior = $item->ID; 
        }
        //adiciona o subsubmenu
    }  
endforeach; 
//necessário para adicionar o último ítem do menu
$menus[] = $myMenu;
?>
```

Como utilizar o código no front end depois de ter feito a classe?

Primeiramente você deverá dar um include ou require_once ou alguma função semelhante de criação de template do wordpress para poder incluir a classe, no exemplo eu coloquei o require_once();

```
<?php require_once (TEMPLATEPATH . '/menu.php'); ?>
```

Depois a criação do menu será fácil, você poderá fazer qualquer tipo de menu customizado com 3 níveis com esta classe, basta aplicar a lógica do menu, no caso eu coloquei um exemplo simples utilizando as tags "UL" "LI" e "A"

```
<ul>
<?php foreach ($menus as $menu) { ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?= $menu->url; ?>">
            <?= $menu->titulo; ?> 
        </a>
    </li>

    <!-- se houver submenu -->
    <?php if ($menu->submenu){ ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach ($menu->submenu as $submenu) { ?>

            <li>
                <a href="<?= $submenu->url; ?>">
                    <?= $submenu->titulo; ?> 
                </a> 
            </li>

            <!-- se for menu de terceiro nível -->
            <?php if ($submenu->submenu){ ?>
                <ul>
                    <?php foreach ($submenu->submenu as $submenu) { ?>
                        <li>
                            <a href="<?= $submenu->url; ?>">
                                <?= $submenu->titulo; ?> 
                            </a> 
                        </li>  
                    <?php } ?>
                </ul>           
            <?php } ?>
            <!-- se for menu de terceiro nível -->  

        <?php } ?>
    </ul>          
    <?php } ?>
    <!-- se houver submenu -->

<?php } ?>
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Assim quando você poderá trabalhar com menu de 3 níveis com o painel de admin do Wordpress e aplicar em seu menu customizado facilmente, como mostrado no exemplo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Opa, deu erro aqui, voce nomeou o menu no WP ou os subitens? Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\BetaNovo\wp-content\themes\BetaNovo\menu.php on line 18

Comment: Olá, acredito que seja por causa que o nome do seu menu do wordpress tem que ser o mesmo da váriavel $menu_name = 'header-menu'; por isto precisa configurar o nome do menu no WP para ele saber qual menu ele precisa pegar, ele está dando erro na  linha 18 no for each por que não conseguiu buscar o array.

Comment: Editei a resposta, caso ainda tenha problemas me de um toque ^~